# If the target of Staggering Strike already started an action, can it do anything else?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, actions

With Staggering Strike, if an enemy moves and provokes an attack of opportunity, I hit it, and it fails the save, it becomes *staggered*.

Staggered:

> A staggered character may take a single move action or standard action each round (but not both, nor can she take fullround actions).

It already started a move action (that was the trigger). **Is it now unable to do anything else in his turn?** (Except maybe a swift action)

I would like to know this for a possible build, where the goal is limiting enemy attacks.
If the enemy can finish its move is not a problem. If the *staggered* condition is valid only for *future* actions, that would not be good for me.

Comment: @HeyICanChan: I fail to see how it matters. I would think that in either case the character was taking a Move Action and it therefore boils down to whether the current Move Action is spent (wasted) or not.

Comment: related https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83426/9671

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The move would be its only action that turn

The Rule of Staggering Strike in the CA says (emphasis mine):

> If you deal damage with a melee sneak attack, you can also deliver a wound that limits your foe's mobility. **For 1 round (or until the target is the beneficiary of a DC 15 Heal check or any magical healing that restores at least 1 hit point), your target is treated as if it were staggered, even if its nonlethal damage doesn't exactly equal its current hit points.** A target can resist this effect by making a successful Fortitude save (DC equal to damage dealt). Multiple staggering strikes on the same creature do not stack. This feat has no effect on creatures no subject to sneak attack damage.

RAW this is read that from the moment the strike hits the target is considered staggered providing he fails his save. This means that at the point where the next action is started after the move the target of the strike is staggered.

The Staggered conditions reads:

> A staggered character may take a single move action or standard action each round (but not both, nor can she take full-round actions).

So if the target wanted to do an action after having moved it could not as at that point is was staggered and already did an move action this turn.

I would argue that if he already did an attack he could still finish his move but that is my opinion/judgement as a DM and your DM might rule differently.